# how to display multiple images in a single line with Kendo?

Tags: json, kendo-ui

I am  new in kendo ui. I have a shopping cart system like this http://demos.kendoui.com/sushi/. I want to show multiple images in a single line by creating image array. the code of this demo site at this address.     https://github.com/telerik/kendo-mobile-sushi.

Comment: If you want multiples, why you do not repeat the `img` element? or you want to iterate on a JSON array inside the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have modified `menu.js` and the entries look like:

```
{
    "id"         : 1,
    "name"       : "Sashimi salad",
    "price"      : 12.00,
    "image"      : "sashimi-salad.jpg",
    "category"   : "Cold starters",
    "description": "Organic greens topped with market fresh sashimi, wasabi soy vinaigrette.",
    "featured"   : true
},
{
    "id"         : 2,
    "name"       : "Chirashi sushi",
    "price"      : 21.00,
    "image"      : [ "chirashi-sushi.jpg", "chirashi-sushi.jpg", "chirashi-sushi.jpg"],
    "category"   : "Cold starters",
    "description": "Sushi bar variety with sushi rice.",
    "featured"   : false
},
```

Where you have entries as `Sashimi salad` that only have one image defined as a `string` and entries as `Chirashi sushi` where have multiple images defined in an `array`.

Then you should modify your templates for checking if `image` is a `string` and if not then iterate on the array elements. Something like:

```
<script id="menuTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a data-role="button"
       data-click="addToCartFromList"
       data-item-id="#:id#"
       href="\\#">#:kendo.toString(price, "c")#</a>
    <a class="details-link" data-role="listview-link" href="\#details?id=#:id#">
        # if (typeof image === 'string') { #
        <img src="content/images/75/#= image #"/>
        # } else { #
        #     for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i ++) { #
        <img src="content/images/75/#= image[i] #"/>
        #     } #
        # } #
        <h2>#:name#</h2>
        <span class="added"#= cartDataSource.get(id) ? "" : 'style="display: none"' #>Item added to cart</span>
    </a>
</script>
```